# ant-design-mobile fonts not loaded

Tags: antd

I followed the example for setting up the ant-design-mobile for react, I'm using `next.js` - the styles are loaded, but not fonts.

I also extracted the HTML and created plain HTML example with full ant-design-mobile CSS and it also doesn't have proper fonts loaded.

See the difference, the font from the official ant-design-mobile [button example](https://mobile.ant.design/components/button/)

[image]

And the font from my example

[image]

P.S. Also - very strange - in the official ant-design-mobile documentation they advise against loading full CSS, but [in its own example](https://github.com/ant-design/antd-mobile-samples/blob/master/web-ssr/pages/_document.js) they actually include the full CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" class="next-head" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://unpkg.com/antd-mobile@2.2.8/dist/antd-mobile.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <a role="button" class="am-button" aria-disabled="false"><span>Start</span></a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the css link and add this to your  component

```
<head>
...
<style global jsx>{`
                    html,
                    body {
                        font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'PingFang SC', 'Hiragino Sans GB', 'Microsoft YaHei', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol';
                        margin: 0;
                    }
`}</style>
 ...
</head>
```